# About packets and proxy Winpcap WPE Pro

Tags: c#, packet, winpcap

I am quite new to programming proxy.   I made a simple packet sniffer.

When i compare the packet from my own packet sniffer and the one I retrieve using wpe pro.

There are additional packets.

[image]
if you look at the picture above..  if i want to send the same packet to server programmically using Sharpcap or winpcap.  How do i deal with the data segment from 0000 to 0030.    The only data i see relevance is C7 77  36 45 30,  which is the what i need to do.

Thanks.